# How to define dojo static variables or static objects by using declare

Tags: javascript, variables, static, dojo, declare

i am playing the dojo today, i have got such a thing i would like to confirm with you dojo experts!

i have created such a sample module, like

```
define("xmodules/staticvartest",  [ "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang"], function(declare, lang) {
    var sttestvar = "staticTestOrginal";
    return  declare("xmodules.staticvartest", null, {
        constructor : function(options) {
            lang.mixin(this, options);
            this.dytestvar = "dynamicTestOrginal";
        },
        setthedata: function(s, d) {
            sttestvar = s;
            this.dytestvar = d;
        },
        show: function() {
            console.log(this.from + ", dytestvar=[" +this.dytestvar+ "],  sttestvar= [" +sttestvar+ "]"  );
        },              
    });
});
```

and i invoke this momdule, as

```
require([ "xmodules/staticvartest" ], function(SVTest) {
     var o1 = new SVTest({
             "from" : "fromobj1",
        });
var o2 = new SVTest({
            "from" : "fromobj2",
        });     
        o1.show();
        o2.show();
        console.log("");

        o1.setthedata("ST_FROM_O1", "DY_FROM_O1");
        o1.show();
        o2.show();
        console.log("");

        o2.setthedata("ST_FROM_O2", "DY_FROM_O2");
        o1.show();
        o2.show(); 
    });
```

And got results:

fromobj1, dytestvar=[dynamicTestOrginal],  sttestvar= [staticTestOrginal]
  fromobj2, dytestvar=[dynamicTestOrginal],  sttestvar= [staticTestOrginal]

fromobj1, dytestvar=[DY_FROM_O1],          sttestvar= [ST_FROM_O1]
  fromobj2, dytestvar=[dynamicTestOrginal],  sttestvar= [ST_FROM_O1]

fromobj1, dytestvar=[DY_FROM_O1],  sttestvar= [ST_FROM_O2]
  fromobj2, dytestvar=[DY_FROM_O2],  sttestvar= [ST_FROM_O2]

from which you have been noticed that **sttestvar** is behaving pretty much like java class static variable!

My question is: Is this **absolutely** correct?  any risky hole? is it safe if i use such coding schema in production? i am not really dojo expert. Any body can provide the info/comment/complaints about my conclusion. Appreciated it very much.

Comment: Please wrap your code in indentation or mark it as code. Your question is unreadable.

Comment: as you may see now it is readable code now, any clue bout question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything immediately wrong with it. One thing is that you need an instance of the class for this to work. The way that I have seen statics in dojo is like this

```
    define([], function(){
        var o = declare(...);
        o.sttestvar = "staticTestOrginal";
        return o;
    });
```

Then you don't need an instance of the class to use that static, ie

```
    require([ "xmodules/staticvartest" ], function(SVTest) {
        console.log(SVTest.sttestvar);
    })
```